# What is deckware?

Tags: semantics

I stumbled upon that word in [this blog post](http://sigusr2.net/2010/Oct/12/this-is-not-the-freehackers-union.html).

There is similar question in [hacker news](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1323231), but without a definitive answer.

Google doesn't seem to be much help either.

Comment: Well I always used "deck" as a keyword for my web apps indicating that the part of the app handles backend requests.

Comment: I saw three guys presenting an 'iPhone app'. It had taken them all night to install Xcode and they managed to produce three static layouts in Interface Builder. They didn't, you know, wire them up to anything. They then said that it was 'really hard'. True deckware story.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Deckware generally refers to "software" that's actually just a [deck of slides](http://www.businessinsider.com/keep-your-pitch-deck-to-six-killer-slides-2010-6) showing how something is supposed/planned/intended to work. In other words, like the "no startup pitches" bit, it's saying "we don't want to see what you plan to build or are starting building, we want to see what you have *built*, and is now **working**."

Answer (score 10):

It refers to a presentation, that is, a deck of slides.  The term is derisive, implying that there is no software at all, merely a presentation about software.  Compare to "vaporware".